# One JFrame and Two JPanels

Tags: java, swing

I'm a newbie in Java and I have a problem regarding panels. I have one `JFrame` and two `JPanels` in my program.

- When I click `button1`, `panel1` will show in the frame.
- When I click `button2`, `panel2` will show in the frame and `panel1` will disappear/hide.

The problem is that `panel1` can't show only `panel2`.  How to show the two panels in this way?

This is my code:

```
public class test{

public static void main(String args[]){

     JButton b1 = new JButton("show p1");
     JButton b2 = new JButton("show p2");
     JLabel l1 = new JLabel("This is p1");
     JLabel l2 = new JLabel("This is p2");

     final JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
     p1.add(l1);
     final JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
     p2.add(l2);
     JPanel buttonPNL = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
     buttonPNL.add(b1);
     buttonPNL.add(b2);

     b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                p1.setVisible(true);
                p2.setVisible(false);   
        }
     });

     b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    p1.setVisible(false);
                    p2.setVisible(true);   
            }
      });

     JFrame frm = new JFrame();
     frm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     frm.add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
     frm.add(p2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
     frm.add(buttonPNL,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     frm.setVisible(true);
     frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frm.setSize(300,300);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet that we can compile. At least describe exactly what the problem is with your current code.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BorderLayout can only handle one component per constraint, that is the moment you add p2 in CENTER, p1 is forgotten. So either do a remove/add in your actionListeners or use another LayoutManager, like f.i. [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).

Answer (score 3):

To achieve such things you need to use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Moreover, Once you remove the old JPanel from the JFrame to add a new JPanel, always do revalidate() and repaint() on the JFrame to realize the changes. Do remember, that only one component can be added at any given time at any given location. Try this code with modifications :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelTest
{
    public PanelTest()
    {
        JButton b1 = new JButton("show p1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("show p2");
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("This is p1");
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("This is p2");

        final JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p1.add(l1);
        final JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(l2);
        JPanel buttonPNL = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPNL.add(b1);
        buttonPNL.add(b2);

        final JFrame frm = new JFrame(); // shifted this line here.

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    // Added by me , these three lines
                    if (p2.isShowing())
                    {
                        frm.remove(p2);
                        frm.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);                   
                        frm.revalidate(); // for JDK 1.7+
                        //frm.getRootPane().revalidate(); // for JDK 1.6 or lower
                        frm.repaint();
                    }
            }
        });

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        if (p1.isShowing())
                        {
                            frm.remove(p1);
                            frm.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);                   
                            // Added by me , these three lines
                            frm.revalidate(); // for JDK 1.7+
                            //frm.getRootPane().revalidate(); // for JDK 1.6 or lower
                            frm.repaint();
                        }
                }
        });


        frm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frm.add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frm.add(buttonPNL,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setSize(300,300);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new PanelTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you can only have one JComponent in CENTER. So wrap the two panels in a panel and only have that in the CENTER:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class JFrameProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JButton b1 = new JButton("show p1"); JButton b2 = new JButton("show p2");

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("This is p1");
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("This is p2");

        final JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p1.add(l1);
        final JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(l2);
        p2.setVisible(false);

        JPanel panelPNL = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panelPNL.add(p1);
        panelPNL.add(p2);

        JPanel buttonPNL = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPNL.add(b1);
        buttonPNL.add(b2);

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                p1.setVisible(true);
                p2.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                p1.setVisible(false);
                p2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        frm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frm.add(panelPNL,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frm.add(buttonPNL, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setSize(300,300);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a tabbed pane for this functionality.  For more details, see [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).

[image: TabbedPaneDemo]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with BorderLayout, you just have to remember to re-add the panel you want to display. You actually get around the revaliation problem already because you're using setVisible().

This is basically what kleopatra said - here's the code:

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("show p1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("show p2");
JLabel l1 = new JLabel("This is p1");
JLabel l2 = new JLabel("This is p2");

final JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
p1.add(l1);
final JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
p2.add(l2);
JPanel buttonPNL = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
buttonPNL.add(b1);
buttonPNL.add(b2);

final JFrame frm = new JFrame();
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        p1.setVisible(true);
        p2.setVisible(false);
        frm.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
});

b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        p1.setVisible(false);
        p2.setVisible(true);
        frm.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
});

frm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frm.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
p2.setVisible(false); // initial state
frm.add(buttonPNL, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frm.setVisible(true);
frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frm.setSize(300, 300);
```